# jquery fancybox hides inline after display

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox 2.1.3 to display the footnotes in a book as inline content. Works beautifully, except that after displaying a footnote, fancybox hides its content.

All the footnotes are grouped at the end of the page, all are visible on load, and I'd like to keep them visible.

Is there an option for fancybox to disable the hiding of inline content?

See http://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/m/mill/john_stuart/m645o/chapter2.html for an example -- footnotes links are superscript 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't an option for disabling the hiding of inline content.  A different approach you could use, however, is to display the contents of the anchor when the link is clicked like this:

```
$(".fn").click(function () {
    $.fancybox($($(this).attr("href")).html());
    return false;
});
```

This will keep the footnotes visible at all times.